# CouchDB MapReduce query for relational data

Tags: javascript, nosql, couchdb, mapreduce

Before I start, please don't tell me to use SQL. This is a small problem in a bigger context and I can't and don't want to use a relational database here. I know the problem is pretty easy to solve in SQL.

There are three types of documents:

- Players
- Teams
- Sponsors

Teams belong to one sponsor but have many players. A player can be in multiple teams and a sponsor can have multiple teams.

Players 1 --- N Teams N --- 1 Sponsors

I put the player document ids into the Teams document in an array:

```
players: ["payer1","player2",...]
```

Now I want all (distinct, only named once) sponsors for a specific player:

Player1: Sponsor1, Sponsor2, Sponsor3,...

It's a bit like the n-n example in the [CouchDB Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EntityRelationship#Many_to_Many%3a_Relationship_documents), but since there are multiple keys in the team-players, that doesn't really work.

I created a [gist with example data.](https://gist.github.com/1388792).

Any idea how to write the MapReduce function to get to this result?

The closest I got, but shows sponsors multiple times, with group level 1:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.type == "team")
    emit(doc.players,doc.sponsor);
}
function(keys, values) {
  return (values);
}
```

Comment: could be useful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511810/couchdb-view-equivalent-of-sum-group-by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close with your view, here it is modified slightly:

```
"playerSponsers": {
       "map": "function(doc) {
                if(doc.type == "team" && doc.players) {
                   for (i in doc.players) {
                      emit([doc.players[i], doc.sponsor],1);
                   }
                }
               }",
       "reduce": "_sum"
   }
```

And here is the query:

```
http://localhost:5984/test/_design/sports/_view/playerSponsors?group=true&group_level=2
```

You will get results like this:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["Player1","Sponsor1"],"value":1},
{"key":["Player1","Sponsor2"],"value":1},
{"key":["Player1","Sponsor3"],"value":1},
{"key":["Player2","Sponsor1"],"value":1},
{"key":["Player2","Sponsor2"],"value":2},
{"key":["Player2","Sponsor3"],"value":1}
]}
```

If you want to get the sponsors for just one player, you can query like this

```
http://localhost:81/test/_design/sports/_view/playerSponsors?group=true&group_level=2&startkey=[%22Player1%22]&endkey=[%22Player1%22,{}]
```