# How to GROUP BY in a CouchDB reduce function

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to get to grips with map/reduce queries when using PouchDB/CouchDB.

I have a lot of documents in my database but I need to create a design that queries the documents and gives me all of the unique team names as a key and then tells me

> a) how many unique wards are within each team
>
> b) the total number of jobs per team (across all wards)

The structure of my data is:

```
{
    "_id": "0448071807c0f37f53e06aab54034a42",
    "_rev": "6-13fd78ada9c8833ec36a01af0acd5957",
    "team": "Team A",
    "ward": "Ward A",
    "date": "2017-03-30",
    "person": "Alice",
    "bed": "Bed 001",
    "jobs": [1,2,3,4]
}

{
    "_id": "0448071807c0f37f53e06aab54034a42",
    "_rev": "6-13fd78ada9c8833ec36a01af0acd5957",
    "team": "Team A",
    "ward": "Ward B",
    "date": "2017-03-30",
    "person": "Bob",
    "bed": "Bed 001",
    "jobs": [1,2]
}   

{
    "_id": "0448071807c0f37f53e06aab54034a42",
    "_rev": "6-13fd78ada9c8833ec36a01af0acd5957",
    "team": "Team A",
    "ward": "Ward C",
    "date": "2017-03-30",
    "person": "Charles",
    "bed": "Bed 001",
    "jobs": [9,5]
}   

{
    "_id": "0448071807c0f37f53e06aab54034a42",
    "_rev": "6-13fd78ada9c8833ec36a01af0acd5957",
    "team": "Team B",
    "ward": "Ward 00",
    "date": "2017-03-30",
    "person": "David",
    "bed": "Bed 001",
    "jobs": [1]
}
```

The output I would expect would be like this:

**Team A**
    - 3 unique wards
    - 8 jobs

**Team B**
    - 1 unique ward
    - 1 job

e.g.

```
{
    "key": "Team A",
    "value": {
        "wards": 3,
        "jobs": 8
    }
}

{
    "key": "Team B",
    "value": {
        "wards": 1,
        "jobs": 1
    }
}
```

My map is currently:

```
{
   "all": {
       "map": "function(doc) { emit(doc.team, doc) }"
   }
}
```

It is the reduce where my struggle comes in.

**EDIT**

I have taken the suggestions used on [CouchDB View equivalent of SUM & GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511810/couchdb-view-equivalent-of-sum-group-by) but this only goes half way towards my challenge.

If I use:

```
{
   "all": {
       "map": "function(doc) { emit([doc.team, doc.ward], 1) }",
       "reduce": "function(keys, values) { return sum(values); }"
   }
}
```

And then go to http://my-ip:5984/wardround_jobs/_design/teams/_view/all?group_level=1 then I see the unique teams (good) and the number of occurrences (also great) but I am unsure how I extend the reduce function to include the total number of jobs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CouchDB View equivalent of SUM & GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511810/couchdb-view-equivalent-of-sum-group-by)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question because on what I learned from that post. It helps but I am still a little stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to emit the jobs length (has the number of jobs) :

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.team,doc.ward],doc.jobs.length);
}
```

Then, you need a reduce function like this :

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  var stats = {uniq:0,jobs:0};
  if (rereduce) {
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
     stats.uniq += values[i].uniq;
     stats.jobs += values[i].jobs;
    }
    return stats;
  }
  stats.uniq = values.length;
  stats.jobs = sum(values);
  return stats;
}
```

For the first iteration, we return an object (stats) with the number of wards perm team (uniq) and the number of jobs (we sum the jobs length of every team/ward.

Then, for the rereduce, we simply aggregate the object`s values.

Comment: That's great and extremely helpful. Thank you.